# window.onload is not firing in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Here is my code:

```
var scrollOnLoad = function scrollOnLoad(selector, offset) {
    window.onload = function() {
        if ($(window).height() <= 800) {
            var attempts = 100;
            var interval = setInterval(function() {
                var h = $(selector).height();
                console.log("attempt #" + attempts + ", h=" + h);
                if (h > 0 || !attempts--) {
                    $("body,html").animate({scrollTop : h + offset}, '1000');
                    clearInterval(interval);
                }
            }, 50)
        }
    }
}
```

and here is how its caling:

```
scrollOnLoad(".content-wrapper", 50);
```

I've noticed that window.onload event is not firing in IE (console is not logging anything) - any ideas why? Thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe `window.onload` is fired before `scrollOnLoad` function is executed?

Comment: is there any way to check if window.onload already was triggered and if yes - fire it programmatycally?

Comment: Why to wrap `window.onload` into a function? Can't you just put it in the global scope, so it could be executed, when `onload` actually fires.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `var scrollOnLoad = function (selector, offset)`?

Comment: no it shouldn't - actually works both ways - its named functions vs anonymous...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `document.readyState` property:

```
function scrollOnLoad(selector, offset) {
    if(document.readyState === 'complete')
        x();
    else
        document.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(){
            if(document.readyState === 'complete')
                x();
        });

    function x(){
        if ($(window).height() <= 800) {
            var attempts = 100;
            var interval = setInterval(function() {
                var h = $(selector).height();
                console.log("attempt #" + attempts + ", h=" + h);
                if (h > 0 || !attempts--) {
                    $("body,html").animate({scrollTop : h + offset}, '1000');
                    clearInterval(interval);
                }
            }, 50)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments your function scrollOnLoad is getting executed after the window has loaded.

Now in better scenarios these events should be added in global scope.

So it should be like

```
 window.onload = function() {
  if(someConditionIsSatisfied){

    if ($(window).height() <= 800) {
            var attempts = 100;
            var interval = setInterval(function() {
                var h = $(selector).height();
                console.log("attempt #" + attempts + ", h=" + h);
                if (h > 0 || !attempts--) {
                    $("body,html").animate({scrollTop : h + offset}, '1000');
                    clearInterval(interval);
                }
            }, 50)
        }
    }
}
```